# Why download speed is limited in firefox and chromium?

Tags: wireless, firefox, chromium, 20.10, download-speed

In chromium and firefox download speed is about 2.0 Mbits/s, but the speed test in those is about 170-200 Mbits/s.

`~$ speedtest`

````
Download: 178.12 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 19.90 Mbit/s``` 

IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Wifi-AP"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point:  
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:12  Invalid misc:43   Missed beacon:0
````

Comment: The test server that speedtest is using is most likely different from where you're downloading files from with chromium/firefox...

Comment: Speedtest tests with the nearest server to you.  Downloading from websites and such has far other implications and a billion other factors and are likely NOT at the location of your speedtest.